# Google AdWords conversion value format

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using google tag assistant in my browser, but google tag assistant always shows

> Conversion Value should be prefixed with standard currency.

i think the reason is the decimal places value at image tag is not picked up:

[image: error example]

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src=""https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxx/?label=xxx&amp;value=267500&middot;00&amp;currency_code=IDR&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0""/>
```

first i used plain `.` as decimal places seperator, and then i used `&middot;` and `&cedil;`, but none of this work

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager is a great tool, but I wouldn't take all of its recommendations at face value.

Adwords itself does have a bit of a storied past when it comes to the meaning of conversion values. For a long time, the value of conversion was just a number with no explicit monetary semantic.

As this is not an optimal setup if you are a multinational advertiser that has to deal with problems such as marketing budgets being denominated in local currencies, the option to define a currency for conversions was added.

Note, however, that the conversion value columns in the Adwords interface still show no currency and that the [`ConversionValue` field in the API](http://ConversionValue) still has type `Double` – as opposed to the [`Cost` field](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/ad-performance-report#cost), which is of type `Money`.

Thus, as far as I can tell, the *only* point where conversion value currencies are important is for situations where a conversion occurs that has a different currency than the billing currency of the Adwords account to which the conversion belongs. In that case, the amount will be converted between the currencies automatically. In all other cases, the conversion value is a number that doesn't care about its currency.

**So, to summarize**: if you use the same currency for both billing and reporting currencies (and don't use things like MCC-level conversion tracking for accounts with different currencies), you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this warning google_conversion_value on script tag should be change or add.
var google_conversion_value = 'currencyhere' + valuehere;

eg
`var google_conversion_value = 'IDR' + 267500.00;`

This warning is very misleading as there's a seperate variable that they can use
`google_conversion_currency` but they require as to append a "currency" prefix on the "value".